# Pluralized many-to-many but still uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As per the below I think this setup is fine:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :traders
  has_many :servicelocations
  has_many :services, through: :servicelocations
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :servicelocations
    has_many :locations, through: :servicelocations
end

class ServiceLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :location
    belongs_to :service
end

class Trader < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end
```

The problem is I am still getting an `uninitialized constant error`.

I have noticed that as I created the model ServiceLocation, funky rails magic created service_location.rb but I am unsure if a) this is the problem and b) how to fix it if it is.

Comment: Post your exact error please.

Comment: `uninitialized constant` what? what's the full error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your error came from this

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :servicelocations
    has_many :locations, through: :servicelocations
end
```

These should be like this

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :service_locations
    has_many :locations, through: :service_locations # notice the underscore
end
```

Your model Class name is `ServiceLocation` and the rails convention name for this is `service_location` not `servicelocation`

And here also,you have to change

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :traders
  has_many :service_locations
  has_many :services, through: :service_locations
end
```

Comment: I was 14 seconds first=)

Comment: @zishe Yup! you are :)

Comment: @Pavan the file name should be `service_location.rb` but the `model` name would be camelcased just like the way he has it: `class ServiceLocation < ActiveRecord::Base`. that's what i'm thinking.

Comment: @WaliAli Not only the filename,but also the name when using with associations should be `serveice_location(singular form)` and `services_locations(plural form)`.

Comment: @Pavan, yes you are right. with associations too. it should be `has_many :service_locations`.

Comment: Sounds good but brings up new error when I create service s and location l then try to perform s.service_locations << l:

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: ServiceLocation(#82194390) expected, got Location(#80132770)

Comment: @JonleePeakman That is another error.Currently one of these answers are the solution for the current error.You should accept one of these answers.

Answer (score 1):

I guess ruby understand `servicelocations` like one word, so you need to change model to `Servicelocation` or change association to `service_locations`. Second method i guess is better, it would be like:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :traders
  has_many :service_locations
  has_many :services, through: :service_locations
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :service_locations
  has_many :locations, through: :service_locations
end
```

Comment: AS above, yeah this is correct bu now when I do service.service_location << location I get:
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: ServiceLocation(#82194390) expected, got Location(#80132770)

Comment: You need to `service.service_locations << location` locationS